# Why would I choose a threaded/process-based approach vs. asynchronous web server

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, webserver, multiprocessing

As I've done some more research into web server software, I've begun to question if Apache's thread/process based method is the way to go vs. the the asynchronous request handling provided by servers like Nginx a Lighttpd, which tend to scale better with heavier loads.

I understand there are many other differences between these latter two and Apache. My question is under what circumstances would I pick a thread/process based method over the asynchronous handling.

1. Are there any features/technologies that I can't use with an asynchronous method (or would function poorly/not as well)?
2. What situations would cause the performance of an asynchronous method to perform worse than a thread/process based approach? Are these common or rare cases, and how big is the difference?
3. Are there any other factors I should take into consideration when comparing the two? Keep in mind I'm focusing mainly on the thread/process based method vs. asynchronous, not any particular server software which happens to utilize one of these methods. These concerns might be difficulty of managing/debugging, security issues, etc.

Comment: Regarding (3): Developer productivity.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by developer productivity. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I think usr means that a threaded server is a lot easier to program and to read than something which handles several requests asynchronously. However, if you handle a single request per pool thread at a time (if your sure that each request can be serviced immediatly), it may be equally easy.

Comment: Actually, async processing lets you support a much greater number of concurrent requests because an async operation is much lighter weight than a thread. Async operations do not imply creating a new thread for each request or managing a thread pool on your own.
However, async patterns are somewhat harder to implement correctly and might result in slightly less readable code.

Answer (score 5):

This is old, but worth answering. Let's first start by saying how each model works.

In threaded, you have a request come in to a handler, the handler spawns a new OS thread to handle that request, and all work for that request happens in that thread until a response is sent and the thread is ended. This model supports as many concurrent requests as threads that your server can spawn (but threads can be somewhat heavyweight).

When doing async a request comes in to a handler but instead of creating a thread to deal with it, it adds the connection to what's known as an event loop. The event loop listens for data/state changes on the connection and fires callbacks each time "something" happens. Once the connection is added to the event loop, the handler immediately listens for new connections to add. This allows you to have many (sometimes 100K) concurrent connections *at the same time*.

> Are there any features/technologies that I can't use with an asynchronous method (or would function poorly/not as well)?

Yes, when you're doing number crunching. The architecture of an async (or "evented") system is such that it is great at *passing data around* but not *processing data*. It can handle thousands of concurrent operations, but because it only runs on *one OS thread*, the callbacks it fires need to do as little as possible to get the most throughput. This is because if one of your callbacks does some number crunching that takes 5 seconds, your entire server *is frozen for 5 seconds* until that operation completes. The idea is to get data, send it to where it's going (database, API, etc) and send a response all with minimal processing.

Async is good for network I/O: passing data between multiple sources/destinations (and also user interfaces, but that's beyond this post).

> What situations would cause the performance of an asynchronous method to perform worse than a thread/process based approach? Are these common or rare cases, and how big is the difference?

See above, but any time you're doing more CPU work than network I/O, you should switch to a threaded model. However, there are architecture workarounds...for instance, you could have an async app, and anytime it needs to do real work, it sends a job to a worker queue. However, if every request requires CPU processing then that architecture is overkill and you might as well just use a threaded server.

> Are there any other factors I should take into consideration when comparing the two? Keep in mind I'm focusing mainly on the thread/process based method vs. asynchronous, not any particular server software which happens to utilize one of these methods. These concerns might be difficulty of managing/debugging, security issues, etc.

Programming in async is *generally* more complicated than threaded. That said, if you're not doing the programming yourself (ie you're choosing between nginx and apache) then I usually recommend you go async (nginx) because you'll generally be able to squeeze more juice out of your server that way. I'm always in favor of using as much async in the stack as possible.

That said, if you're programming an app and trying to decide whether to use a threaded or async model, you will have to take developer time into account. Unless you're using a language that has green threads over an event loop (like scheme), expect to tear your hair out quite a bit over rogue exceptions crashing your entire app and in general wrapping your head around [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)/using callbacks for everything. Futures/promises are your friend, but are only a bandaid to make async nicer.

#### TL;DR

Async, when used in a server, can squeeze (a lot) more concurrent operations than threading *if you're doing network IO and nothing else*.

If you're doing any kind of number crunching, either use a threaded app server *or* use an async app with a background queuing system.

Async is a lot harder to program in unless your language supports "fake" threading over it (ie green threads). Once you get past the initial hump you're fine, generally. If you don't have green threads, use promises.

If you have the choice between threaded and async as a component in your stack (apache vs nginx), and they provide the *exact same features*, slightly favor async. Don't just pick it because you think it will make everything 20x faster though.

Answer (score 0):

Processes have several advantages compared to threads and async models related to security and reliability. Most websites don't need these particular advantages, but sometimes they're indispensable.

1. Security: you can run your worker processes in a sandbox, as a low privileged user, and handle only one request per worker process. This mitigates against some kinds of security vulnerabilities: even if an attacker takes over your entire worker process, as long as you sandboxed it tightly based on request metadata (i.e. it doesn't have write access to all your data), then it can't harm system stability or affect the responses made to requests.
2. Security #2: sometimes you need to sandbox untrusted code, or to enforce segregation between different code or different requests, and the only way to do this is with a separate one-shot process. (Think running user-provided code.)
3. Reliability: memory leaks and memory corruption are much less severe if you teardown and replace worker processes regularly (or for each request).
4. It's easy to enforce hard limits on CPU time, disk and network quota, etc. spent on handling a user request in a separate process. Even if the request-handling code goes into an infinite loop, the master process (or the OS) can enforce a timeout.

Comment: 5. for reasons beyond your convenient control, your process may get blocked on (e.g.) a disk I/O you didn't explicitly initiate. If your work is spread across multiple processes, work can continue in the other processes. If it's a jillion threads in a single process, they are all frozen until that operation completes, significantly impacting throughput.